# How is kernel size in keras convolution layers defined?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

According to the documentation website (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) the kernel size of a keras convolution layer is defined as **height x width**:

> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the
>   height and width of the 2D convolution window. Can be a single integer
>   to specify the same value for all spatial dimensions.

In the code documentation however it is defined as the exact opposite:

> kernel_size: An integer or tuple/list of 2 integers, specifying the
>               width and height of the 2D convolution window.
>               Can be a single integer to specify the same value for
>               all spatial dimensions.

Which one is true? As far as I figured out, the definition of the website should be the right one, am i right?

Comment: What do you mean by code documentation? And I had checked in [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L379) arguments for `Conv2D`. It has the exact information which has in website.

Comment: hm interesting. I just copied the description from the installed keras package I am using. Must have been updated.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the definition in the website is correct (height x width). The code documentation was fixed in version 2.2.0 as per this commit.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/commit/027d37961afff8a7963836ca87ccdbbf65a78811#diff-d462a3275abee3aa77ba2b341e45cf20L366